# Why does it take so many attempts to generate a random value between 1 and 10000?

Tags: javascript, loops, random, while-loop

I have the following code that generates an initial random number between 1 and 10000, then repeatedly generates a second random number until it matches the first:

```js
let upper = 10000;
let randomNumber = getRandomNumber(upper);
let guess;
let attempt = 0;

function getRandomNumber(upper) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * upper) + 1;

}
while (guess !== randomNumber) {
  guess = getRandomNumber(upper);
  attempt += 1;

}
document.write('The randomNumber is ' + randomNumber);
document.write(' it took' + attempt);
```

I am confused at (attempt) variables. Why is it that the computer took this many attempts to get the `randomNumber`?  Also, it didn't put attempt in the loop condition.

Comment: Are you aware that your code never allows to find the `randomnumber` on first guess? I'd suggest reading [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Also what do you consider too many attempts for a range of 100000?

Comment: Please tell how attempt variable worked. and how it showed that it attempted this much

Comment: And you allows the same guessed number to be asked for again and again and again...

Comment: What do you expect here? The Computer has a range of 10.000 numbers at hand. You do not presuppose that there is no possibility of repetition either. So it could take a million rounds until the randomly generated guess matches the randomNumber.

Comment: @AKA - I tried to clarity the text of your question.  Feel free to roll back if my changes were not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you a start. This is what your code does:

```
// define the maximum of randomly generated number. range = 0 - 10.000
let upper = 10000;

// generate a random number out of the range 0-10.000
let randomNumber = getRandomNumber(upper);

// predefine variable guess
let guess;

// set a counter to 0
let attempt = 0;

// generate and return a random number out of the range from 0 to `upper`
function getRandomNumber(upper) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * upper) + 1;
}

// loop until guess equals randomNumber
while (guess !== randomNumber) {
  // generate a new random number and assign it to the variable guess
  guess = getRandomNumber(upper);

  // increase the counter by 1
  attempt += 1;
}

// output the initially generated number
document.write('The randomNumber is ' + randomNumber);

// output the number of repetitions
document.write(' it took' + attempt);
```

So, once again. You generate a random number at start. And then you repeat generating another random number until this second random number matches the first. As you don't set any limits e.g. "each random number can only appear once" or "no more than 10.000 tries" your program might need millions of tries until the number matches, because you have a range of 10.000 possible numbers and they might repeat a hundreds of times each before the match is finally there.

Try to optimize your program by limiting the number of tries to 10.000. And you could your computer just let count upwards from 0 to 10.000 instead of guessing with a randomly generated number.

Answer (score 1):

When I repeatedly run your snippet, I am seeing your code take anywhere from a few thousand to a few tens of thousands of repetitions to get a given value for a random number sampled between 1 and 10000.  But this is not surprising -- **it is expected**.

Assuming your `getRandomNumber(upper)` function does indeed return a number between `1` and `upper` *with a uniform distribution*, the expected probability that the number returned *will not* be the initial, given value `randomNumber` is:

```
1 - (1/upper)
```

And the chance that the first `N` generated numbers *will not* include the given value is:

```
(1 - (1/upper)) ^ N
```

And so the chance `P` that the first `N` generated numbers *will* include given value is:

```
P = 1 - (1 - (1/upper)) ^ N
```

Thus the following formula gives the number of repetitions you will need to make to generate your initial value with a given probability `P`:

```
N = ln(1.0 - P) / ln(1.0 - (1.0/upper))
```

Using this formula, there is only a 50% chance of getting `randomValue` after 6932 repetitions, and a 95% chance after 29956 repetitions.

```js
let upper = 10000;

function numberOfRepetitionsToGetValueWithRequiredProbability(upper, P) {
  return Math.ceil(Math.log(1.0 - P) / Math.log(1.0 - (1.0/upper)))
}

function printNumberOfRepetitionsToGetValueWithRequiredProbability(upper, P) {
  document.write('The number of tries to get a given value between 1 and ' + upper + ' with a ' + P + ' probability: ' + numberOfRepetitionsToGetValueWithRequiredProbability(upper, P) + ".<br>");     
}

var probabilities = [0.10, 0.20, 0.30, 0.40, 0.50, 0.60, 0.70, 0.80, 0.90, 0.95, 0.99, 0.9999];

probabilities.forEach((p) => printNumberOfRepetitionsToGetValueWithRequiredProbability(upper, p));
```

This is entirely consistent with the observed behavior of your code.  And of course, assuming `Math.random()` is truly random (which it isn't, it's only pseudorandom, according to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)) there is always going to be a vanishingly small probability of never encountering your initial value no matter how many repetitions you make.